# The method onClick(View) from the type new Thread(){} is never used locally

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I'm attempting to multithread my code, but when I put the `OnClickListener` in a new `Thread`, this error comes up in Eclipse:

```
The method onClick(View) from the type new Thread(){} is never used locally
```

My code of `MainClass`:

```
public class MainClass extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    public float goldCount;
    Button minionClick;
    Button storeClick;
    Button storeDismiss;
    TextView textGoldCount;
    ImageView spinningBars;
    String textTotal;
    private SharedPreferences prefs;
    PopupWindow pw;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        setContentView(R.layout.mainlayout);

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        PopupWindow pw = new PopupWindow(inflater.inflate(R.layout.storemenu, null, false));
        storeDismiss = (Button) pw.getContentView().findViewById(R.id.menudismissid);

        Animation rotation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.spinningbarsanimation);
        rotation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
        spinningBars.startAnimation(rotation);

        prefs = getSharedPreferences("LeagueClicker", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        goldCount = prefs.getFloat("goldCount", 0.0f);

        minionClick = (Button) findViewById(R.id.minioncentreid);
        storeClick = (Button) findViewById(R.id.storeimageid);
        textGoldCount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textviewtop);
        spinningBars = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.spinningbarsid);
        textTotal = goldCount + " Gold";

        textGoldCount.setText(textTotal);
        textGoldCount.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "mechanical.ttf");
        textGoldCount.setTypeface(tf);
        textGoldCount.setTextSize(35);

        minionClick.setOnClickListener(this);
        storeClick.setOnClickListener(this);
        storeDismiss.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        prefs.edit().putFloat("goldCount", goldCount).commit();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        goldCount = prefs.getFloat("goldCount", 0.0f);
        t.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        prefs.edit().putFloat("goldCount", goldCount).commit();
        Log.d(prefs.getFloat("goldCount", 0.0f) + "derprolw", "ejwfjbrea");
    }



    Thread t = new Thread() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch (v.getId()) {

                case R.id.minioncentreid:
                    goldCount += 1.0;
                    prefs.edit().putFloat("goldCount", goldCount).commit();
                    textTotal = goldCount + " Gold";
                    textGoldCount.setText(textTotal);
                    textGoldCount.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                    break;

                case R.id.storeimageid:
                    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) MainClass.this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

                    View popupview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.storemenu, null);
                    final PopupWindow pw = new PopupWindow(popupview, 300, 450);
                    pw.showAtLocation(v, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);

                    storeDismiss = (Button) pw.getContentView().findViewById(R.id.menudismissid);
                    storeDismiss.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            pw.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
                    pw.showAsDropDown(storeClick, 0, 0);
                    break;
            }
        };

    };

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

    }
}
```

The `Thread` is at `Thread t = new Thread()`. Does anyone one know why this happens, and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you define the click listener for a view via the XML it looks for the listener in your Activity, not any random threads you may have created. Your architecture needs changing so that the onClick is in the Activity, and then that method uses the thread instead

Answer (score 0):

The problem is nothing calls the `onClick` method of your inner `Thread`, so Eclipse gives you this warning.

You currently have no way to assign `t` as the onClickListener to any of your views. Right now you've assigned `this` (meaning the existing instance of the Activity) to be the listener, and so the Activity's `onClick` method will be called, not the thread's `onClick` method. You could do either of these thigns:

1. Define an inner class that extends `Thread` and implements `OnClickListener`, create an instance of that, and then assign the instance as the onClickListener to those views.
2. Put the switch statement back into the Activity's `onClick` method. Inside of that, where you want to do work in a background thread, create and start the `Thread` there.

Even those still will not work because some of the things you are trying to do in the onClick callback are things which *must* be done on the UI thread, so moving them to another thread will actually cause errors in your app.

This is not the sort of thing you want to move to a background thread anyway. You should use background threads for long-running operations that actually can *block* the UI thread, like network operations and disk I/O. If you want to understand how, when, and why to use concurrency, perhaps you should look for some good reading material (such as Concurrency in Java).

Answer (score 0):

When you set your `OnClickListeners` in your `Activity` `MainClass` like this:

```
minionClick.setOnClickListener(this);
storeClick.setOnClickListener(this);
storeDismiss.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Then you are setting the `Activity` as listener and not the thread. The method that will be called when a click happens is the one at the bottom of your `Activity` class:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

}
```

And not the one inside your `Thread`. I think the part that is confusing you is the following:
When you do something like this:

```
Thread thread = new Thread() {

};
```

Then you are actually creating a whole new class - called an anonymous class - which is a subclass from `Thread`. So if you define a method in their then it doesn't belong to the `Activity`, it is actually in a completely different class.

Another thing to consider is that what you are trying to do is not a good idea anyways. What you should do is start the thread in the `OnClickListener` and not handle the click in a separate `Thread`. Try something like this:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    Thread thread = new Thread() {
        ...
    };        
}
```

Anyway it looks like an `AsyncTask` would be much better suited than a `Thread` in this case. And from what I can see in your code threading shouldn't even be necessary in this portion. You don't actually perform any complex tasks which would require running them in a separate `Thread` and as such any threading would just be counterproductive. The code most likely runs a lot better and smoother without any threading.