# The method onClick(View, String) from the type new View.OnClickListener(){} is never used locally

Tags: java, android, encryption, sms, smsmanager

These codes below are used to encrypt SMS using PRINCE algorithm and sends the SMS to the receiver. Currently I am facing a problem where `public void onClick(View v,String args)` gives an error message of "**The method onClick(View, String) from the type new View.OnClickListener(){} is never used locally**". I have also referred to [The method onClick(View) from the type new Thread(){} is never used locally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23327988/the-method-onclickview-from-the-type-new-thread-is-never-used-locally) but the solutions given does not help me. Is there any other solution for this problem?

```
    btnSendSMS.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String phoneNo = txtPhoneNo.getText().toString();
         String message = txtMessage.getText().toString();
         if (phoneNo.length()>0 && message.length()>0)
         {
              LongBuffer messageBuf = TooLong.messageToLongBuffer(message);
              messageBuf.flip();
              long[] messageData = new long[messageBuf.remaining()];
              LongBuffer i = messageBuf.get(messageData);
              String v1=prince.Encrypt(i, k0, kop, k1, t);
              sendSMS(phoneNo, v1);
          }
          else
               Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
               "Please enter both phone number and message.",
               Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    });        
    }

//---sends a SMS message to another device---

   private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String v1)
   {      
         /*
         PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                    new Intent(this, test.class), 0);                
         SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
         sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, pi, null);        
         */

         String SENT = "SMS_SENT";
         String DELIVERED = "SMS_DELIVERED";

         PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
                new Intent(SENT), 0);

         PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
                new Intent(DELIVERED), 0);


//---when the SMS has been sent---
      registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){
      @Override
         public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
         switch (getResultCode())
         {
            case Activity.RESULT_OK:
             Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS sent", 
               Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             break;
            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
             Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Generic failure", 
               Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             break;
            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
             Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No service", 
               Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             break;
            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
             Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Null PDU", 
               Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             break;
            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
             Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Radio off", 
               Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             break;
         }
      }
     }, new IntentFilter(SENT));

//---when the SMS has been delivered---
     registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){
     @Override
        public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
        switch (getResultCode())
        {
            case Activity.RESULT_OK:
             Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS delivered", 
               Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             break;
            case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
             Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS not delivered", 
               Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             break;         
        }
       }
            }, new IntentFilter(DELIVERED));        

           SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
           sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, v1, sentPI, deliveredPI);               
        }    
       }
```

Comment: where have you setonclicklistener part are you specifying the method in layout.xml file.

Comment: are you there or you issue is solved.

Comment: @piyush, I could not understand your question

Comment: Are you sure its an error or just a warning ?

Comment: @Sharpedge it's a warning but my app does not work with it

Comment: laalto's answer is far most near to correct. One thing, have you initiated this btnSendSMS.setOnClickListener in onCreate() method of activity or not ? If that is the case then why have you created a new method private void sendSMS in the body of onCreate() ???

Comment: Can you edit your question with the whole class code...? to help you better

Answer (score 1):

The signature for an `onClick()` method is `onClick(View)`, not `onClick(View,String)`. The latter declares a new method that is never called and does not override the method in `OnClickListener` interface.

Remove the `String` argument from your method, and remove the other stub `onClick(View)`.

Comment: the app crashes when I did as mentioned.

Comment: Then there's another bug. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Answer (score 0):

```
public void `onClick(View v,String args)`
```

This method is never used locally because this method is an method written by you. OnButtonclick your method never get called. On click the `onClick(View)` method get invoked. Write your code inside `onClick(View)`

Comment: tried that and it crashed. The log is 11-12 15:47:14.496: E/AndroidRuntime(13396):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Answer (score 0):

```
          btnSendSMS.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {


    // why have you written this method it not called from anywhere remove this 
       method put  code in public void onClick(View v) method
                 public void onClick(View v,String args) 
                 {

                 }
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String phoneNo = txtPhoneNo.getText().toString();
                 String message = txtMessage.getText().toString();
                 if (phoneNo.length()>0 && message.length()>0)
                 {
                      LongBuffer messageBuf = TooLong.messageToLongBuffer(message);
                      messageBuf.flip();
                      long[] messageData = new long[messageBuf.remaining()];
                      LongBuffer i = messageBuf.get(messageData);
                      String v1=prince.Encrypt(i, k0, kop, k1, t);
                      sendSMS(phoneNo, v1);
                  }
                  else
                       Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                       "Please enter both phone number and message.",
                       Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            });        
            }


if you require this method (onClick(View v,String args) )then comment.
```

Comment: I have done that and the app crashed with log 11-12 15:47:14.496: E/AndroidRuntime(13396):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: 11-12 15:56:22.391: E/MoreInfoHPW_ViewGroup(14309): Parent view is not a TextView
11-12 15:56:22.471: D/TextLayoutCache(14309): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
11-12 15:56:22.471: D/TextLayoutCache(14309): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
11-12 15:56:22.476: D/TextLayoutCache(14309): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
11-12 15:56:22.476: D/TextLayoutCache(14309): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
11-12 15:56:22.491: D/libEGL(14309): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_mali.so
11-12 15:56:22.496: D/libEGL(14309): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_mali.so

Comment: 11-12 15:56:22.501: D/libEGL(14309): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_mali.so
11-12 15:56:22.501: E/(14309): Device driver API match
11-12 15:56:22.501: E/(14309): Device driver API version: 29
11-12 15:56:22.501: E/(14309): User space API version: 29 
11-12 15:56:22.501: E/(14309): mali: REVISION=Linux-r3p2-01rel3 BUILD_DATE=Tue Jul 22 19:59:34 KST 2014 
11-12 15:56:22.596: D/OpenGLRenderer(14309): Enabling debug mode 0
11-12 15:56:22.616: D/TextLayoutCache(14309): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
11-12 15:56:22.621: D/TextLayoutCache(14309): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter

Comment: 11-12 15:56:31.781: E/AndroidRuntime(14309):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
11-12 15:56:31.781: E/AndroidRuntime(14309):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
11-12 15:56:31.781: E/AndroidRuntime(14309):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-12 15:56:35.731: I/Process(14309): Sending signal. PID: 14309 SIG: 9

Comment: I could not paste all the logs so the first 2 are the beginning lines and the 3rd comment is the last lines in the log.

Comment: please edit the question and post your logs there and also your activity so that every one have a look thanks.